# I have two sampling techniques $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$. Given $x=\varphi_1(u)$ can I compute a $v$ with $x=\varphi_2(v)$?

Tags: sampling, random-variable, quantiles

I have two sampling surjective techniques $\varphi_1,\varphi_2:[0,1)\to E$ mapping a random number $u\in[0,1)$ to a sample in a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$.

Say $u\in[0,1)$ and $x:=\varphi_1(u)$. Is there any chance to compute the random number $v\in[0,1)$ which would have produced the same sample $x$ under $\varphi_2$, i.e. $x=\varphi_2(v)$?

Clearly, if (for example) $\varphi_1$ is not injective, $\varphi_1$ might be constant on an interval and hence we're not able to identify a unique random number producing $x$. However, maybe we can somehow commit to a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is too vague in my opinion as there must be constraints on the transforms $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ for this to happen. Namely that the realised value of $X_1$ as $x=\varphi_1(u)$ must be a possible value of $X_2$ as well, namely that $x$ must belong to the support of $X_2$ for a $v$ such that $x=\varphi_2(v)$ to exist.

With this constraint in mind, an approach to the problem is to consider that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are the inverse cdfs of the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, namely$$\varphi_i(u)=F_i^-(u) = \sup \{x;\ F_i(x)\le u\}\qquad i=1,2$$(under the convention that cdf's are left-continuous). Either $x$ is a continuity point for $F_2$ and then
$$v=F_2 \circ F_1^{-1}(u)$$
(since $F_2$ is then invertible at this point).
For this is a discontinuity poiny, meaning it is an atom, in which case
$$v\in \{\nu;\ \lim_{{y \to x}\\{y< x}} F_2(y)\le \nu\le \lim_{{y \to x}\\{y> x}} F_2(y)\}$$
This includes the special value
$$v=F_2 \circ F_1^- (u)$$

Comment: I will take a look at what you wrote. Just let me add that my question was motivated by section 6 here: https://cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/bitterli18reversible.pdf. Maybe there is an additional assumption that I don't see for the moment.

Comment: Regarding your answer: I've forgot to mention that I want to assume that $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are surjective.

Comment: And, clearly, the problem with your solution is that it only works for $E=\mathbb R$, doesn't it? Actually, I'm willing to assume that $E$ is a Banach space, but I don't see how the notion of a CDF generalizes to this case. The case $E=\mathbb R^3$ is interesting for me as well.

Comment: You want to generate a three dimensional random variate from a single uniform??

Comment: Well, no. Sorry. I think I made some mistakes in my attempt to simplify my concern. For the case $E=\mathbb R^3$, I'm actually using a sample from a unit (hemi-)sphere.

Comment: Could you provide a proof of $v\in \{\nu;\ \lim_{{y \to x}\\{y< x}} F_2(y)\le \nu\le \lim_{{y \to x}\\{y> x}} F_2(y)\}$ or point me to a reference?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: This is simply a description of the interval of uniforms producing the same realisation $x$, since $x$ has positive mass.

Comment: I've described my actual concern more precisely in a separate question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/443580/222528. It would be great if you could take a look.