# Use of the inversion method in sequential sampling to "invert" a random walk

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, random-walk, quantiles, sequential-monte-carlo

Let $M\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be Borel measurable, $\lambda$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathcal B(M)$, $k\in\mathbb N$, $I:=\{0,\ldots,k\}$, $q$ be a probability density on $\left(E^I,{\mathcal E}^{\otimes I},\lambda^{\otimes I}\right)$ and $\nu:=q\lambda^{\otimes I}$. Assume that $$q(x)=q_0(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^kq_i(x_{i-1},x_i)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E^I\tag1$$ for some Borel measurable $q_0:M\to[0,\infty)$ and $q_i:E^2\to[0,\infty)$, $i\in I\setminus\{0\}$.

> In a computer program, I generate a sample $x$ from $\nu$ by a random walk. Vertex $x_i$ is selected in dependence of $x_{i-1}$ by drawing some random numbers from $(0,1)$. This process can be described by a surjective Borel measurable transformation $\varphi:(0,1)^d\to E^k$ with $$\mathcal U_{(0,\:1)}^{\otimes d}\circ\varphi^{-1}=\nu\tag1,$$ where $d\ge k$ is sufficiently large. What I need now is to reverse this process: Given $x\in E^k$, I need to find $u\in(0,1)^d$ with $x=\varphi(u)$. How can we do that?

*Remark*: The inversion process I'm after is described [here in Chapter 5](https://benedikt-bitterli.me/master-thesis/master-thesis.pdf#chapter.1) and [here in Section 6](https://cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/bitterli18reversible.pdf).

Note that this is somehow related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/443580/222528), since if $q$ is a probability density on a measure space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R),\lambda)$, $F$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of $\nu:=q\lambda$ and $\varphi$ denotes the quantile function of $\nu$, then $$\mathcal U_{(0,\:1)}\circ\varphi^{-1}=\nu.\tag3$$

Comment: Is $d > k$?  "$d \in \mathbb{N}$ is sufficiently large" doesn't clarify the situation much, at least not to me.

Comment: @jbowman Yes, $d\ge k$.

Comment: @jbowman I've boiled the problem down as much as possible. It would be great if you could take a look: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/444481/222528.